# Удаление с Realm

Tags: android, база-данных, realm

Правильно ли я удаляю с Realm?

```
Event event = response.body();
                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                event = realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("id", eventID).findFirst();
                event.deleteFromRealm();
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();
```

Comment: Можно оффтопный вопрос? Дайте ссылку на эту бибилотеку, я прям чую, что она полезная, как ничто другое.

Comment: @metalurgus https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: @metalurgus Realm - стопроцентная no-SQL ORM, написана на С++, очень быстрая и удобная. В андроид близких аналогов нет. Конечно же она полезная, как ничто другое :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендуется выполнять операцию в параллельном потоке. Здесь с учетом того, что ID гарантировано уникальный:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
   @Override
   public void execute(Realm realm) {
      realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("id", eventID).findFirst().deleteFirstFromRealm();
}
});
```

Для удаления нескольких записей, подходящих под условие, строка примет вид:

```
realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("id", eventID).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если это касается объекта, который получен с базы, то есть является управляемым. То можно удалять без повторного поиска объекта в базе.

```
mRealm.beginTransaction();
myObject.deleteFromRealm();
mRealm.commitTransaction();
```